# Django - Override manager for specific many-to-many relationship field

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

Say I have a model like so:

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    services = models.ManyToManyField(
        'models.Service', through='common.AppointmentService')
```

What I want to do is override the field to return a specific queryset (something like below which doesn't obv work):

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    services = models.ManyToManyField(
        'models.Service', through='common.AppointmentService')

    @property
    def services(self)
        return super(Appointment, self).services.all_with_deleted()
```

#### Details on the scenario:

I am implementing soft delete.

I soft delete the Service model, removing any "deleted" services from the application by setting a `deleted_at` field. But in regards to appointments that already exist with that service, I need to respect those services and not "delete" them. So, everywhere I use `appointment.services` I would need to call `appointment.services.all_with_deleted()`. But I don't want that littered throughout my code. The model should abstract those details away via a custom manager or overridden field.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as a potential solution for those it may help.

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    services = models.ManyToManyField(
        'models.Service', through='common.AppointmentService')

    # alias this field so we can override it on each instance as a property
    _services = services

    @property
    def services(self):
        '''appointments should ignore soft deleted team member services'''
        return self._services.all_with_deleted()

    @services.setter
    def services(self, srvs):
        self._services.set(srvs)
```

My confusion came from not distinguishing between properties and attributes. Getters and setters are not defined for attributes of python classes, but `@property` does define `__get__` and `__set__` methods on each instance of the class.

#### EDIT:

This breaks queries. You'll now need to write queries like:

```
Appointment.objects.filter(_services__in=[1,2,3])
```